# Return Only number from a string if it contains numbers

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, substring

For example,
string is `abc123CD` need to find out a method to read only *numbers* in the string 
i.e.

```
  select a_postgres_function('abc123CD')

  ------
  Result
  ------
  123
```

---

*My try*

```
 select substring('abc123CD' from '%#"^[0-9]+$#"%' for '#')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select (regexp_matches('abc123CD', '\d+'))[1];
```

Since `regexp_matches` returns array of text, you should access the first element by `[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

As per [ntalbs's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25681789/3682599)

---

Wrap that query into a *Function*

```
create or replace function shownums(text) returns integer as 
$$
select (regexp_matches($1,'\d+'))[1]::int; 
$$
language sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all digit characters from the string (not just the first group), it is easier to remove all characters, which aren't a digit:

```
select regexp_replace('abc123CD45ef', '[^\d]+', '', 'g');

-- regexp_replace
-- --------------
--    '12345'
```